# How to pass the query result to another method

Tags: java, sql

I am querying

```
select empname 
from employee 
where empsal > 5000
```

I got 3 rows (one column having 3 rows) and now I want to return this as string array.

And then I want the strings in the String array as separate string

Comment: What is stopping you? That is a very basic task / request you should be able to easily solve on your own. *If* you cannot do that you should at least show us what you have tried so far, how you are executing the select statement, etc.

Comment: you need to create one list<Claas> and class with properties

Comment: you only need to do a method that returns the list (For Example) that you create when the query was executed

Answer (score 1):

A more object oriented approach would be to loop through the resultset as proposed, but instead of assigning Strings in an array, create an object that encapsulates the data you are retrieving from the database. You are limiting yourself too much by simply storing Strings in an array.  Use an object that reflects your business needs / domain.

For example:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}

class DataAccessor {

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {

        List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        String query = "select empname, empsal from employee where empsal>5000";

        // Create the database connection & statement somehow...
        Statement stmt = createStatement();

        try {
           ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(query);

           while (results.next()) {
               Employee employee = new Employee();
               employee.setName(results.getString(1));
               employee.setSalary(results.getInt(2));
               employeeList.add(employee);
           }
        } finally {
           stmt.close();
        }

        return employeeList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your `ResultSet` with `rs.next()` and then add each row to an `ArrayList<String>`. Then you can get your "separate strings" by their index.